# tree-view filter table AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try in view something like this :

```
/big_big_package
/door 
   /cooler
   /chair
```

html :

```
<div ng-repeat="i in split">
    <div ng-repeat="s in i">
        <a ng-click="Paths(s)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="left-menu-link">
            {{s}}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
[
    "/big_big_package", 
    "/door/cooler", 
    "/door/chair", 
    "/door"
]
```

Plunker  : http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire I want in view something like this : (on top of question)

Comment: instead of :                                                                                       /big_big_package
/door/cooler
/door/chair
/door

Answer (score 0):

I tried your question. This is my approach,

1. sort the array, so that we will get the folder structure in order.
2. Loop through the array while checking if the previous elements is contained in the current element.
3. add padding if the element is found.

Please check my Plunkr for the GIST of my approach. This is just a basic example, which works on a single level, but you need to tweak this function for it to work on multilevels.

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

**JS:**

```
vm.getid = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api.json',
        })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                var data = data.data;
                data.sort();
                var prev = 0;
                angular.forEach(data, function(val, index){
                  var padding = '0px';
                  var skip = true;
                  var repl = "";
                  console.log(val);
                  console.log(prev);
                  console.log(val.indexOf(prev)>-1);
                  if(val.indexOf(prev)>-1 && index !== 0){
                    padding = '20px';
                    data[index] = {padding: padding, value: val.replace(prev, "")};
                    skip = false; 
                  }else{
                    data[index] = {padding: '0px', value: val};
                  } 
                  if(skip){
                    prev = data[index].value;
                  }
                });
                $scope.id = data;
                console.log(data); 
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });

    };
```

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="i in id">
      <a ng-style="{ 'padding-left' : i.padding}" ng-click="Paths(i)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="left-menu-link">
          {{i.value}}
      </a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way could be to split the strings by `/`, then build up a tree for those items that only have one entry with all those items which have twice (or more) entries, and where the first entry matches. Finally remove items which is placed in a tree :

```js
var tree = data.data.map(function(d) {
  return d.split('/').slice(1)
})
tree.forEach(function(t) {
  if (t.length == 1) t.tree = tree.filter(function(f) {
    if (f != t && f[0] == t[0]) {
      f.processed = true;
      f.shift();
      return f
    }
  })
})
tree = tree.filter(function(t) {
  if (!t.processed) return t
})
$scope.id = tree;
```

To make tree like indention use nested `<ul>`'s

```html
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="i in id">
   {{ i[0] }}
   <ul ng-if="i.tree">
     <li ng-repeat="t in i.tree">
       {{ t[0] }}
     </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/NDLqM7Yo2w9oJUsmxi37?p=preview